# Datagridview Bulk insert on click event

Tags: c#, sql, datagridview, bulkinsert, datagridviewcolumn

I have this piece of code that inserts whatever I copy from my excel file, into my datagridview, where i continue to insert (bulk insert) into my database. 
My problem is that when I paste into my datagridview the first row becomes (and overtakes) my column names, and I'm not sure why:
Code as follows :

```
private void btnBulkAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DataObject o = (DataObject)Clipboard.GetDataObject();
            if (o.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.Text))
            {
                if (dgvIntake.RowCount > 0)
                    dgvIntake.Rows.Clear();

                if (dgvIntake.ColumnCount > 0)
                    dgvIntake.Columns.Clear();

                bool columnsAdded = false;
                string[] pastedRows = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Split(o.GetData(DataFormats.Text).ToString().TrimEnd("\r\n".ToCharArray()), "\r\n");
                int j = 0;
                foreach (string pastedRow in pastedRows)
                {
                    string[] pastedRowCells = pastedRow.Split(new char[] { '\t' });

                    if (!columnsAdded)
                    {
                        for (int i = 0; i < pastedRowCells.Length; i++)
                            dgvIntake.Columns.Add("col" + i, pastedRowCells[i]);

                        columnsAdded = true;
                        continue;
                    }

                    dgvIntake.Rows.Add();
                    int myRowIndex = dgvIntake.Rows.Count + 1;

                    using (DataGridViewRow myDataGridViewRow = dgvIntake.Rows[j])
                    {
                        for (int i = 0; i < pastedRowCells.Length; i++)
                            myDataGridViewRow.Cells[i].Value = pastedRowCells[i];
                    }
                    j++;
                }
            }
        }
```

As for my Bulk insert button :

```
private void btnBulkInsert_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string strQuery;
            try
            {
                using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source = ROTIMSQL01; Initial Catalog = TDB; Persist Security Info = True; User ID = adiM; Password = Mohan@1234"))
                {
                    using (SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand())
                    {
                        comm.Connection = conn;
                        conn.Open();
                        for(int i=0;i<dgvIntake.Rows.Count; i++)
                        {
                            strQuery = @"INSERT INTO [dbo].[TestTable] VALUES " + dgvIntake.Rows[i].Cells["ID"].Value + ","
                                + dgvIntake.Rows[i].Cells["Other1"].Value + ",'" + dgvIntake.Rows[i].Cells["Other2"].Value + "'," + dgvIntake.Rows[i].Cells["Other3"].Value + ","
                                + dgvIntake.Rows[i].Cells["Other4"].Value + "," + dgvIntake.Rows[i].Cells["Other5"].Value + ")"; 
                                comm.CommandText = strQuery;
                            comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

What am I doing wrong? 
Thank you in advance !

Answer (score 1):

On Excel, it doesnt exist 'columnname', what you see that is **'values' TOO** in excel.

The only column name in excel is like A,B,C,D,E....Z,AA,AB,AC......

so it is normal then you pasted the columnname in first row.

So two solution:

1. Might needs to take controls on columnnames in first row.
2. Should not to copy the columnnames when in Excel.